# How to monitor error on a validation set in Chainer framework?

Tags: neural-network, chainer

I am kind of new to Chainer and have written a code which trains a simple feed forward neural network. I have a validation set and a train set and want to test on the validation set on each like 500 iterations and if the results are better  I want to save my network weights. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```python
optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.setup(model)

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=0)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (10000, 'epoch'), out='result')

trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(validation_iter, model, device=0))
trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport())
trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'main/loss',  'validation/main/loss', 'elapsed_time']))
trainer.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Error on validation set

It is reported by `Evaluator`, and printed by `PrintReport`. Thus it should be shown with your code above. And to control the frequency of execution of these extentions, you can specify `trigger` keyword argument in `trainer.extend` function.
For example, below code specifies printing each 500 iteration.

`trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'main/loss',  'validation/main/loss', 'elapsed_time']), trigger=(500, 'iteration'))`

You can also specify trigger to `Evaluator`.

2. Save network weights

You can use snapshot_object extension.

http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.extensions.snapshot_object.html

It will be invoked every epoch as default.

If you want to invoke it when the loss improves, I think you can set `trigger` using `MinValueTrigger`.

http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.triggers.MinValueTrigger.html